# AlarmManager Android trigger alarm every day at 10 AM

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I would like to run automatically, each day at predefined time (for. example at 10 AM) some code in my app.

I trying to do using the:

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 120 , pi);
```

But setRepeating accepts only time in miliseconds.

I would like to ask, is possible to set something like 10:00, REPEAT_DAILY ?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, tenOclockToday,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

You'll need to set `long tenOclockToday` equal to the millisecond value of 10:00 today (unless it is past 10:00, then you can set it to 10:00 tomorrow). You'll need to use a `Calendar` instance and set the time to 10:00, then get the milliseconds from the Calendar using `calendar.getTimeInMillis()`

Comment: Thanks for reply: 

I tried to do the following way:

// Set firing of the receiver in predefined time each day
Calendar firingAt = Calendar.getInstance();
firingAt.set(Calendar.HOUR, 21); // At the hour you wanna fire
firingAt.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 54); // Particular minute
firingAt.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // particular second
long millis = firingAt.getTimeInMillis();
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, millis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , pi);

Toast.makeText(context, "TIMER SET", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

But my solution is not working.